# How can I resize this canvas to 50vh?

Tags: javascript, resize

Hello everybody I want this script in my site but I'm not sure how to resize this. It currently occupies the full width of the canvas 200vh but I want it to 50vh.

[image]

Comment: From image details, the  canvas dimensions are 1300 by 903 pixels, so what are you asking about viewport dimensions - what is the problem and what is the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting the width to 50vh explicitly?

Also are you aware that `vh` is proportional to the height of the viewport, not the width? If you want to be proportional to the width you'll need `vw`.